# Tools and methods for live-monitoring ASP.NET web applications?

Tags: asp.net, performance, monitoring, production

I think many developers know that uncomfortable feeling when users tell them that *"The application is slow (again)."*

In a complex web application there can be **many possible reasons** for a degradation in (perceived) performance: slow database response, bandwidth issues, bad caching etc. There certainly are issues which will never occur in a development or staging environment.

Now my question:

Is there a set of tools and/or methods which would provide **a comprehensive "live" state on a IIS/ASP.NET/SQL Server production system** in a visually way (not just performance counters):

- Current HTTP requests (say the last n minutes)
- Exceptions / timeouts
- Bandwidth data
- Number of open database connections / database calls
- ...

The primary goal is to see at a glance (or after looking closer) what problem is causing the performance problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the category of software you're looking for is ".net profiler" or ".net tracer". One such tool that you might consider is JetBrains' [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). It gives you runtime stack traces and an array of counters that indicate possible bottlenecks.

Answer (score 4):

Previously mentioned tools will certainly work. At our shop we needed finer information and built our own solution (long story: it was easier to code than to argue about tools and retrievable data).

I used [LogParser](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1287) to flip through the IIS logs and create output reports of those logs (e.g. result code breakdowns etc).

I used a combination of performance counters and WMI values to get the rest - you can read these using some pretty straightforward C# - this gives you full control that you can then dump to .csv etc for viewing/processing in excel or if you are updating a page as a control center.

I would probably also look at [IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/) as a great resource for IIS tools including debugging, security etc.

Comment: I just checked out iis.net and found a good article posted just a few days ago: http://blogs.iis.net/timamm/archive/2012/02/11/asp-net-and-iis-performance-troubleshooting-tools-3-key-resources.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I followed [urig's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259105/tools-and-methods-for-live-monitoring-aspnet-web-applications#259242) and found [this software called SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/products/smartinspect/).

Does anybody know this logging/monitoring tool? It seems to be a combination of real time console and developer library.

Answer (score 1):

CLR 4.5 will have some new capabilities that will help you monitor ASP.NET performance live - without restarting your app. Basically you can re-JIT your code to include some monitoring-hooks in it, and then inspect time spent in classes/methods etc.

I'm sure dotTrace and other profiling tools will leverage this automatically, but it's worth checking out: [C9 - Inside Re-JIT with David Broman](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/CLR-45-David-Broman-Inside-Re-JIT)