# Health Monitoring of Application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, monitoring, wcf-data-services

Our application is platform which contains WinForms based Fat Client UI, Window Services, WCF Service, and Web Services. We want to develop one centralize portal where we can verify status of various interested components; e.g. whether all the services are up, whether service is consuming large amount of memory. And we want to know if something is wrong with any service e.g. it is coming down, end of with exception proactively.

Can you suggest any tool, methods, features in .net that you guys have used...

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277238/distributed-monitoring-service-using-c-sharp-net-3-5

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate your apps with Microsoft System Center Operation manager (SCOM - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/operations-manager.aspx). Probably this solution is too heavy weight but anyway you should take it into consideration.

Comment: I am more interested in Application Monitoring rather than Server/infrastructure monitoring..

Comment: As i know you can write some kind of plugin for SCOM so it will work with your apps and its data. Like custom performance counters and monitors for your app. it will be usefull for admins who already use SCOM so they can motitor your app the same way they do it to monitor infrastructure and other apps

Comment: Can you forward me to any link which explains how can I write custom plugin for SCOM ? Also if my admin does not use SCOM then any other idea about the same...